# FB login with oauth-5-laravel Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: No response

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, authentication, oauth

I try to use oauth-5-laravel package for fb login,
but got error at **`$token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);`**

Here is laravel error message :

```
TokenResponseException in StreamClient.php line 68:
Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: No response
```

and I try to `dd($code)`, it is not empty! 
here is my controller code :

```
$code = $request->get('code');
$fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

if (!is_null($code))
 {

    $token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);
    $result = json_decode($fb->request('/me?fields=id,gender,name,email,birthday'), true);

    dd($result);
}
else
{
    $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();
    return redirect((string)$url);
}
```

what the problem is ?

Comment: How its posible that 'code' has something? I can't understand it. I'm trying to test it using:
`Route::get('test', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    $code = $request->get('code');
    $googleService = \OAuth::consumer('Google');
    $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);
    dd($token);
});`
But obviously it doen't work.. I don't know how to populate that 'code' variable and what it is... plz help!