# Use oauth-5-laravel and get TokenResponseException

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth

from my previous question on stackoverflow : 
[FB login with oauth-5-laravel Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: No response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051395/fb-login-with-oauth-5-laravel-failed-to-request-resource-http-code-no-response][1])

I have found an alternation solution by changing this line of code from : 
`$fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');`

to

```
$OAuth = new OAuth();
$OAuth::setHttpClient('CurlClient');
$fb = $OAuth::consumer('Facebook',route('rgstFb'));
```

After that I have faced some error as below :

```
TokenResponseException in CurlClient.php line 135:
Error # 7: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused
```

I did google this keywords, and find a rule said:

```
1- CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host 
2- Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host
3- CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:1f02:face:b00c:0:26: Network is unreachable

The first and second problem are usually more general, and can occur due to many reasons, for example your host might have port 80 or port 443 blocked, and your facebook api will fail to connect.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Socialite?

Comment: using oriceon/oauth-5-laravel package